# I have 2 random.randint values, how do I make the 2nd one come up?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Apparently I've made a lot of mistakes, I'm pretty new to Python so that's why.

I have a `random.randint` within an `if` statement and another one within an `elif` statement. But the 1st one comes up even when I put my input to an answer that's supposed to take me to the second one (E.g. `prank`).

This is my code:

```
import random
LOL = raw_input('Do you want a meme or a prank idea? ')
if LOL == 'meme' or 'Meme' or 'MEME':
x = random.randint(1, 5)
    if x == 1:
        print('Yee')
    elif x == 2:
        print('Yeet!')
    elif x == 3:
        print('I got the horses in the back')
    elif x == 4:
        print('AND HIS NAME IS JOHN CENA!!!!')
    elif x == 5:
        print('IT\'S OVER 9000!')
  elif LOL == 'prank' or 'Prank' or 'PRANK':
        y = random.randint(1, 3)
    if y == 1:
        print('Replace their Oreo frosting with toothpaste.')
    elif y == 2:
        print('Blast into their room with an air horn.')
    elif y == 3:
        print('Blast the FBI meme on a loud speaker on max volume')
```

It shows the one of the memes even when I write "prank" and I think it's because the `random.randint` goes anyways and since it's first, it goes first and overlaps the second `random.randint`.

Comment: `or` doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't really make sense. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/357835) for how to format code.

Comment: Try `if LOL.lower() == 'meme':` (which would avoid your abuse of the `or` operator)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: I have added an answer, hope it will help you

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT yes it did :)

Comment: @JohnColeman How am I abusing the 'or' operator?

Comment: `LOL == 'meme' or 'Meme' or 'MEME':` doesn't mean `LOL == 'meme' or LOL == 'Meme' or LOL == 'MEME':`. Instead it means `(LOL == 'meme') or 'Meme' or 'MEME':` which *always* evaluates to `True` (since nonempty strings are truthy).

Comment: At first I was confused why it worked when I added the 'LOL ='' to every "meme"  but it makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using or operator in the wrong way

**Try this:**

```
import random
LOL = raw_input('Do you want a meme or a prank idea? ')
if LOL == 'meme' or LOL == 'Meme' or LOL == 'MEME':
  x = random.randint(1, 5)
  if x == 1:
    print('Yee')
  elif x == 2:
    print('Yeet!')
  elif x == 3:
    print('I got the horses in the back')
  elif x == 4:
    print('AND HIS NAME IS JOHN CENA!!!!')
  elif x == 5:
    print('IT\'S OVER 9000!')
elif LOL == 'prank' or LOL == 'Prank' or LOL == 'PRANK':
  y = random.randint(1, 3)
  if y == 1:
    print('Replace their Oreo frosting with toothpaste.')
  elif y == 2:
    print('Blast into their room with an air horn.')
  elif y == 3:
    print('Blast the FBI meme on a loud speaker on max volume')
```

**Output**

```
Do you want a meme or a prank idea? prank
Blast the FBI meme on a loud speaker on max volume
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess `random.choice` more suitable here ? =)

```
import random

LOL = input("Do you want a meme or a prank idea? ")

prank_or_meme = {
    "meme": [
        "Yee",
        "Yeet!",
        "I got the horses in the back",
        "AND HIS NAME IS JOHN CENA!!!!",
        "IT'S OVER 9000!",
    ],
    "prank": [
        "Replace their Oreo frosting with toothpaste.",
        "Blast into their room with an air horn.",
        "Blast the FBI meme on a loud speaker on max volume",
    ],
}

default = ["Philosoraptor: I don't know, may be it\'s a joke?"]

values = prank_or_meme.get(LOL.lower(), default)
print(random.choice(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you arent using `or` right, you need to do like this:

```
if LOL == 'Meme' or LOL == 'meme' or LOL == "MEME":
```

You should use a method named `lower` or `upper` instead, like this:

```
if LOL.lower() == 'meme':
```

Or this:

```
if LOL.upper() == 'MEME':
```

Second, your indentantion not make sense, I will GUESS that you mean:

```
import random
LOL = raw_input('Do you want a meme or a prank idea? ')
if LOL == 'meme' or 'Meme' or 'MEME':
    x = random.randint(1, 5)
    if x == 1:
        print('Yee')
    elif x == 2:
        print('Yeet!')
    elif x == 3:
        print('I got the horses in the back')
    elif x == 4:
        print('AND HIS NAME IS JOHN CENA!!!!')
    elif x == 5:
        print('IT\'S OVER 9000!')
elif LOL == 'prank' or 'Prank' or 'PRANK':
    y = random.randint(1, 3)
    if y == 1:
        print('Replace their Oreo frosting with toothpaste.')
    elif y == 2:
        print('Blast into their room with an air horn.')
    elif y == 3:
        print('Blast the FBI meme on a loud speaker on max volume')
```

Why your doesnt work? Cause `if` receives a boolean value and text string are read like a true value, so when you do:

```
if 'Im a string':
    print('I will be printed')
```

The text is printed. Try use my above suggestions.
@John Coleman and @jonrsharpe were right.